# How to duplicate directory in git, tracking new files?

Tags: git, directory

Is there a simple way to create a copy of a folder in a local repository, keeping track of exactly the same files (do not care about commit history, or untracked files)?

The folder contains a hierarchy of both tracked and untracked (but not ignored) files and directories. I basically want to recursively replicate the tracked structure. Is there a way other than copying everything, and then manually adding only the relevant files (there are a lot of them)?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your needs. It seems vague to me.

Comment: Does your directory contain any untracked files?  If not, it seems it would be as simple as `cp dir dir2 && git add dir2`.

Comment: Note that history, in Git, consists of commits: nothing more, nothing less. You cannot make commits without making history, and you cannot modify any previous commits, though you *can* copy old commits to new ones and then stop *using* the old commits (that's how Git implements "rewriting history").

Comment: @0x5453 is spot on, just duplicate the folder, add it, and commit it.

Comment: @0x5453 thanks, precised the question. The directory contains a mix of tracked and untracked  files (in a hierarchy). It's basically an existing component, from which I want to create and develop a new different component, keeping track of both old and new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to `git clone` the directory. Need to then take care of the remote origin url (which otherwise is set to the clone source). For example:

```sh
# Clone the repository
git clone <existing directory> <new directory>

cd <new directory>

# Set origin url to the same one as old repository
git remote set-url origin `git -C <existing directory> config --get remote.origin.url`
```

Another, slower option is to just clone from a remote repository (github / bitbucket?) which is @Sergey_S 's solution - which means downloading everything again.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't care about the history, you could just copy the directory and then `git add` it:

```
$ cp -R old_dir new_dir

$ git add new_dir

$ git commit -m "first revision of new_dir's copied files"
```

Comment: thanks, precised the question - there are untracked files which I don't want tracked in the copy either. Wondered if there's a simpler way than adding the relevant files one-by-one

Answer (score 1):

You can go to your intended directory and clone your git project again.

```
$ cd "new_directory"
$ git clone "your_project_git_address"
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to develop and track the two copies separately - here a commit in one would interfere with the other

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have **two separately same projects in git**, follow this command lines:

```
$ mkdir "duplicated_project"
$ cd "your_project_path"
$ sudo cp -R * "duplicated_project_path/"
```

Then you must add/define this duplicated project on git, so you can follow:

> Adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line tutorial:

[GitHub Reference](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)

**Or**

You can duplicate your project in web ui:

i.e. if you are using from the [Gitlab](http://gitlab.com) you can duplicate/export your project, such as bellow instruction:

- In the left side in **Setting** tab --> select **General** --> expand **Export project** --> click on **export**.

Then  follow this command line:

```
$ git clone "duplicated/exported_project"
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

<sub>In these mentioned approaches have not interfered commits.</sub>

Comment: seems that this way I still need to select the new files manually to be tracked (did I miss something)? 
Also, ideally I would like to have two folders in the same project, not separate repositories

Answer (score 1):

Basically your question is how to separate versioned files from unversioned.
This answer assumes you set up a server where you push your repo for backup, etc.
Push your branch dev to the server origin: git push origin dev
Note, only the versioned files go to the server.
Look at the server with a web browser and find the folder you want to copy. 
Right click on the folder you want to copy and select download as zip. 
In windows make a folder new_project. Copy folder from the zip file to new_project. 
Now you copied all your versioned files to new_project. 
Add the new project to git: git add new_project.
This will add the folder new_project, all files and sub folders to git in one command.
Enjoy your new project.

Comment: Thanks! This would certainly work for github and bitbucket, and although I was searching for an answer using git commands rather than server interface (which may depend on the server) - this is the closest to an answer in 3 years!